# Open MP force periodic synchronization

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to use Open MP (C++) to parallelize my parallel tempering code for Monte Carlo Simulations on a 3D Ising Lattice. Here N (generally something like 8) independent Monte Carlo simulations are run at differing temperatures. The simulations and all their variables/quantities are completely independent from one another. 
Periodically one must stop the simulations and attempt to exchange their configurations - this is where the trouble is. Attempting to force the threads to stop (so that swapping can occur properly without quantities being changed at the same time) using a barrier fails and the compiler gives the error: "work-sharing region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing, critical, ordered, master or explicit task region."

Is there any way around this? How can I restructure my code so that it will compile and run? I have looked through a number of similar threads but in my case loops cannot be separated easily if at all (simulation progress must be retained).

Here is a rough outline of my code (leaving lots out).

```
#include "omp.h"//and other headers

#define LSize 10
#define TotalRuns 10
#define MC_WarmUP 10000
#define MC_Samples 50000

using namespace std;
int main()
{
     //rng initialized
     int numruns;
     int Lattice[TotalRuns][LSize][LSize][LSize];//explicit (for swapping)

     omp_set_num_threads(TotalRuns);
     #pragma omp parallel for//run simulations entirely independently
     for (numruns=0;numruns<TotalRuns;numruns++)
     {
          int counter,counter2,counter3;
          double SimEnergy[TotalRuns];
          double Temp;
          //file setup (each simulation also prints its results to file)
          //Lattice[numruns] is initialized to random +1/-1's

          for (counter=70;counter>1;counter++)//i.e for a number of temperatures
          {
              Temp = 0.1*(double)counter + 0.1*(double)numruns;//set temperature
              for (counter2=0;counter2<MC_WarmUP;counter2++)//equilibrate the simulation
              {
                   //perform Monte Carlo iterations here

              }
              for (counter2=0;counter2<(NSamples/SwapSteps);counter2++)//sampling phase
              {
                   for (counter3=0;counter3<SwapSteps;counter3++)//take samples ever SwapSteps interations
                   {
                        //perform Monte Carlo iterations here
                        //save simulation quantities periodically
                   }
                   SimEnergy[numruns] = E_Calc(Lattice,numruns);//calculates the energy of the lattice for a given simulation

                   #pragma omp barrier//need everything to stop at this point
                   #pragma omp single//only one thread does this
                   {
                        //bunch of stuff here but most importantly
                        swap(Lattice[N],Lattice[M])//may occur where N,M are between 0 .. TotalRuns and N!=M.
                   }
              }
              //save averaged data to file
          }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Code is quite simple and perhaps not the best way to go about things. Question really is how can I freeze or lock threads such that the swap can take place without the Lattice being modified during the swap operations? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: From your question it is unclear where in the code write to `Lattice` happen. It is not even clear where `N` and `M` come from and how the swap affects further iterations. "entirely independently" can't be true if you need this "exchange". Please try to clarify how `Lattice` is divided up, where read and write accesses to which parts are happening.

Comment: Lattice reads and writes are occurring wherever "//Monte Carlo interations here" is commented. I'm guessing that my approach with Lattice is not the best but I need to compare values derived from Lattice between simulations. N and M are irrelevant placeholders, the take away is that the Lattice[] that each simulation has access to may be swapped at 'random' between simulations. The simulation then continues iterating with its 'new' Lattice.

Comment: If you swap elements of `Lattice` "at random", you are totally out of luck and must protect each and every access to `Lattice` with a critical section. Try to make the code truly independent. The question as is cannot be answered in a constructive way without clear information about the access patterns.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify. Lattice is a 4D array(Lattice[numruns][LSize][LSize][LSize]). Each simulation is only swapping the last three indices of Lattice. I.e. Simulation 1 only touches Lattice[numruns=1][][][]. The whole Lattice construct can be completely different - I just need a way for each simulation to independently work on its distinct Lattice (Lattice[LSize][LSize][LSize]) and then be able to explicitly compare and swap Lattices between threads.